# Pause loop until download event is complete

Tags: c#

How can I pause the loop in someRandomMethod() until the code in DownloadCompleted() have been executed? This code below only unpacks the latest version in the versions array. It's like the loop is faster than the first download and m_CurrentlyDownloading have the latest value the first time DownloadCompleted() is beeing executed.

```
private void someRandomMethod() {
    for (int i = 0; i < versions.Count; i++)
    {
        //ClearInstallFolder();
        m_CurrentlyDownloading = versions.ElementAt(i);
        Download(versions.ElementAt(i));
        LocalUpdate(versions.ElementAt(i));
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}

private void Download(string p_Version)
{
    string file = p_Version + ".zip";
    string url = @"http://192.168.56.5/" + file;

    //client is global in the class
    client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\tmp\" + file);
}


private void DownloadCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        Unpack(m_CurrentlyDownloading);
        if (GetInstalledVersion() == GetLatestVersion())
            ClearZipFiles();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Why do you use an async API if you want a synchronous one in the first place? oô

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way would be to not use the `*async` methods. The normal DownloadFile will pause execution until it completes.

But if you've got access to the Await keyword, try this.

```
private async Task Download(string p_Version)
{
  string file = p_Version + ".zip";
  string url = @"http://192.168.56.5/" + file;

  //client is global in the class
  client = new WebClient();
  client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(DownloadCompleted);
  client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressChanged);
  await client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\tmp\" + file);
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go. Or use an AutoResetEvent and set it on the DownloadCompleted

Comment: Ty for your answer! I couldn't use this, I got "Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier. Are you targeting the wrong framework version, or missing a reference to an assembly?" (I'm targeting 4.0). However, you mention I should not use *async methods. Is there any alternatives? :)

Comment: Try `client.DownloadFile(new Uri(url), @"C:\tmp\" + file);`

Comment: Ty, you will get accepted sir! What's the name of the CompletedEventhandler for the non async one? Can't find anything about it :S

Comment: You don't need a CompletedEventHandler for the non async one, because the next line of code doesn't execute until it completes- just call the event handler yourself in the next line.

Answer (score 0):

something like this can be used to wait

make it class property

```
      bool IsDownloadCompleted=false;
```

Add this in  **DownloadCompletedEvent**

```
      IsDownloadCompleted=true;
```

and this where you want to stop loop

```
   while(DownloadCompleted!=true)
  {
     Application.DoEvents();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create some boolean variable, create a delegate and get\set methods for this variable. 
Then just in loop made smth like :

```
while(!isDownLoadCompleted)Thread.Sleep(1024);
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use Paralel.ForEach. this loop will wait until all threads done.
check Here for how to use : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx 
or
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx